# Libreoffice Writer text cursor width in Linux

Tags: linux, libreoffice-writer

I know one can [easily change](http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=43873) LibreOffice Writer's text cursor width in Windows. But I'm on Linux, and fail to find similar feature. How can I change this width in Linux?